# Language support with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, citing, languages

I'm writing my Bachelorthesis in english. I am using TexnicCenter and bibtex. The preamble has the following values:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\usepackage[numbers, square]{natbib}
```

reduced to (maybe) relevant entries.

The section references is added with

```
\selectlanguage{english}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\bibliography{content/bibliography}
```

however e.g. the entry

```
@misc{TICPI2015,
    Author = {Transparency{\ }International},
    Date-Added = {2016-11-01 17:23:00 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2016-11-01 17:23:00 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {01.12.2016},
    Title = {{Transparency International} - The Global Anti-Corruption Coalition},
    Url = {http://www.transparency.org/cpi2015},
    Urldate = {2016-11-01},
    Year = {2016},
    language = "English"
}
```

looks like the following:

[image]

which is german and not english (the word *Abruf* instead of *Last Checked*). Also in project settings, the project language is set to *en* and dialect to *US*.

How can I make the entries in references in english?

Comment: The problem is style `alphadin`, which includes the informations in german. Change it to an english one (sorry, I do not know one). I asked for an MWE, a minimal working (or not) example, which makes it much more easier to test your problem and to help you ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using BibTeX and a German style (`alphadin`). In this style all words are coded in German. BibTeX by itself, and `natbib` as bibliography-package do not support language change. Neither `babel` nor `csquotes` have anything to do with it.

You have three possibilities:

No. 1: Use an English style, for example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[numbers, square]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{TICPI2015}

\selectlanguage{english}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{Lit}
\end{document}
```

No. 2: Switch to `babelbib` (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babelbib) instead of `natbib`, where you have full language support while staying with BibTeX, but can only use citation styles predefined by `babelbib`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{TICPI2015}

\selectbiblanguage{english}
\bibliographystyle{babalpha}
\bibliography{Lit}
\end{document}
```

No. 3: Switch to BibLaTeX, where you have native full language support, lots of styles available, and can customise everything to your liking on the go.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Lit.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{TICPI2015}

\selectlanguage{english}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is with `\usepackage[babel, british=quotes]{csquotes}`.

You can also try this :

```
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
```

Then when you call `\selectlanguage{english}`it should switch languages.

Comment: with `\usepackage[babel, british=quotes]{csquotes}` I get the error `Package xkeyal Error: british undefined in families csq.` and the second soption doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Correct would be `\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} \usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}`. However, this will not solve your problem. `alphadin` is a German style and has no english versions of those words (as most of the other styles have no German versions). Neither `babel` nor `csquotes` have anything to do with that, BibTeX is simply not able to have this kind of adaptability.