# Changing 'and' in citation (citet, citep)

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm writing something in Dutch.

I use author-year citations (using the package `natbib` and the bibliographystyle `unstrnat`). But when there are two authors, `citep` and `citet` generate these citations:

```
\citet{Pious2012}   % an article by Pious and Prévost in my bibliography
\citep{Pious2012}
```

gives:

Pious and Prévost (2012)
(Pious and Prévost, 2012)

The word "and" isn't Dutch so needs to be changed to "en". I have no idea how to do this. In the preamble and at the beginning of the document I specify the language as Dutch but `citep` and `citet` seem to ignore this. Does anyone know how to change the "and"?

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,dutch,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{Pious2012,
       author = {Piou, Cyril and Pr\'{e}vost, Etienne},
       title = {A demo-genetic individual-based model for Atlantic salmon populations: Model structure, parameterization and sensitivity},
       journal = {Ecological Modelling},
       volume = {231},
       pages = {37-52},
       ISSN = {0304-3800},
       year = {2012},
       type = {Journal Article}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{dutch}

Here is: \citet{Pious2012} and \citep{Pious2012}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Part of the bibliography is in the mwe (`filecontents`).

As you can see, I use "and" in my bibliography, I think that's necessary for LaTeX to recognise that there are different authors.

Comment: You need another bibliographystyle. Or drop natbib and bibtex and switch to biblatex and biber. There the language support is build in.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347850/language-support-with-bibtex/359815#359815)!

Comment: Cedric, I edited your example because most of it was not needed to demonstrate your problem and it was not compileable as it stood.

Comment: Thanks, Paul Stanley. I'll keep those things in mind next time I post something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer notes, this is hard-baked into the `unsrtnat.bst` file. If it's your *only* problem, though, you can proceed as follows:

- Find a copy of `unsrtnat.bst`, either on your system or on CTAN.
- Rename that, so that it's called something like `unsrtnat-nl.bst`.
- Modify it. Don't try to understand it! Just open it in a text editor and look for the appearances of the string `" and "` (including the quotes). You will find it in three functions.
- Change `" and "` to `" en "`. Save the file.
- Use `unsrtnat-nl` as your `bibliographystyle`
- Wait until the next time you find something hardcoded there that you need to change and switch to `biblatex`

Comment: Thanks! I did as you said and my citations were changed. The "and" was still there in the actual bibliography, though. But I found another .bst file online which changed that "and" too, to "&". So I just replaced the " \& "  by " en " and that solved that problem, too. Thank you very much. I also had to delete the usual "helper files" (.aux, .bbl, .blg, ...) to make this work.