# Natbib IEEE in Dutch?

Tags: natbib, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I want my bibliography in Dutch. I use natbib IEEE. How can I ajust this so everything is in Dutch?

Comment: Or if you are willing to switch to BibLaTeX instead of Natbib then you can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362300/correct-output-format-of-page-number-using-cite-command together with `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}` to translate the bibliography.

Comment: See these two: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361255/changing-and-in-citation-citet-citep and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347850/language-support-with-bibtex/359815#359815

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "so everything is in Dutch". Are you talking about connectors such as `and`, or also about strings such as "In" and "edited by"?